# How To Prevent This Exception?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, oledb

what i got:

two mdb databases and one application to insert information (rows) from db1 to db2.

when i'am runing my code there is an exception:

```
System resource exceeded.
```

the code:

Connection Strings:

```
Dim db2Connection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\db2.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;")

Dim db1Connection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\db1.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;")
```

Code to copy the information:

```
Dim DataAddapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
Dim ds As New DataSet

'Open DB1 Connection:

db1Connection.open()

'Select All From M

DataAddapter.SelectCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM M", db1Connection)
Dim cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand = DataAddapter.SelectCommand
Dim Reader As OleDb.OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

'Before Reading Results From DB1 Lets Open DB2Connection:
db2Connection.open()

'Start Reading Results in LOOP:
        Do Until Reader.Read() = False
            Dim F_Name As String = Reader("F_NAME")
            Dim L_Name As String = Reader("L_NAME")
            Dim CITY As String = Reader("NAME_CITY")
            F_Name = Replace(F_Name, "'", "")
            L_Name = Replace(L_Name, "'", "")

'Start Moving The Results To Db2(Insert):
'--------------------------------------


                Dim Exist As Integer = 0
                Dim c As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
                c.Connection = db2Connection
                c.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `Names` WHERE `LastName`='" & L_Name & "' AND `FirstName`='" & F_Name & "' AND `City`='" & CITY & "'"
'----------------------------------------
'Exception Here!! :(
'This Line Checking If Already Exist
                Exist = CLng(c.ExecuteScalar())
'----------------------------------------

                If Exist = 0 Then
                    c.CommandText = "INSERT INTO `Names` (`LastName`,`FirstName`,`City`) VALUES ('" & L_Name & "','" & F_Name & "','" & CITY & "')"
                    c.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    'Note: After this line i'am getting the Exception there... (2 queries executed ExecuteScalar + ExecuteNonQuery) maybe i need to create connection for every query? :S

                End If
       Loop
```

another thing:
i have to send the query to **db2** in this syntax(Otherwise it does not work):

```
INSERT INTO `Names` (`LastName`,`FirstName`,`City`) VALUES ('" & L_Name & "','" & F_Name & "','" & CITY & "')
i have to use the ->  `  <- to the name of the columns,
but when i'am sending a query to db1 without  ->  `  <-  it's working. :S and i dont know what is the difference between db1 to db2 but its very strange maybe my problem is there...
```

good answer is a good example plus good explanation :).(c# or vb.net)

Comment: In case you are using Access 2010: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2726928/en-us . It could maybe fix your issue

Comment: @DanielAbouChleih i tried it, still the same :/

Comment: Have you tried moving `Dim c As New OleDb.OleDbCommand : c.Connection = db2Connection` outside the loop?

Answer (score 0):

You are prime for sql-injection... You should read-up on that, and at a minimum, PARAMETERIZE your sql commands, do NOT build string statement to execute with embedded values.  I don't specifically know how db2 handles parameters... some use "?" as place-holders, SQL-Server uses "@" and Advantage Database uses ":".. but in either case, here is the principle of it...

```
c.CommandText = "select blah from `names` where LastName = ? and FirstName = ? and City = ?"

c.CommandText = "select blah from `names` where LastName = @parmLastName and FirstName = @parmFirstName and City = @parmCity"
```

For the named parameters above (such as @parmLastName), I am prefixing with "parm" for sole purpose of differentiating a value vs the actual COLUMN name

Then, your parameters would be something like

```
c.Parameters.Add( "@parmLastName", yourLastNameVariable )
c.Parameters.Add( "@parmFirstName", yourFirstNameVariable)
c.Parameters.Add( "@parmCity", yourCityVariable)
```

If using the "?" version of parameters where they are not explicitly named, you need to just make sure your parameter context is in the same sequence as the "?" place-holders.

Then execute your call... Same principle would apply for all your queries (select, insert, update, delete)

---

As for your system resources... how many records are you pulling down.  It could just be choking your system memory resources trying to pull down the entire database table.  You might want to break down based on one alphabetic letter at a time...

[Also, a link from MS about system resources and Access via a patch.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2726928)

Comment: That's no solution, not even addressing the problem -1

Comment: @DanielAbouChleih, the original portion may not have specifically addressed the issue, but obviously lacking SQL from a basic security perspective. I've revised my answer/comment after other additional searching for the user. which was the same you posted.

Comment: @DRapp: First part fits for a comment, but not for an answer because not answering a question does not fit into the Q&A-System of Stackoverflow. Your second part just does not contain any new information. As you can see my comment below the question just linked to the same page your link does. He already checked it and it didn't solve his problem

Comment: @DanielAbouChleih, I do agree with you, but sometimes in such a condition as this, I would bend the rules so-to-speak as to help prevent bad coding practices in the future.  The only other option I offered as part of the answer was to do in smaller select segments processing alphabetically one letter query process per cycle to hopefully pull down / work with smaller data set.  It could be due to excessive string manipulations and not getting through garbage collection.

Comment: @DRapp: Right, I just realized you suggested to reduce the amount of records by querying one letter at a time. On the one hand I can understand your position (because SQL-Injection is a really important part), on the other there'll may be a visitor seeking for solution and he'll find this post which doesn't solve his issue. Nevermind, I just revoked my -1